# Почему filter: blur() иногда размывает края в белый цвет, а иногда нет

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Вот пример, когда filter не размывает края (края чёрного цвета относительно)

```css
.card {
  width: 365px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, black, #3d3d3db0 49%, black 100%);
  will-change: box-shadow;
  transition: .3s;
}

.card__active .card__title {
  transition: .4s;
}

.card__active:hover .card__title--hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.card__active:hover .card__body--animation {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card__body--animation {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(200px);
  transition: .4s;
}

.card__body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.card__title--hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: .4s;
}

.card:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateY(-10px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.card__img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: .3s;
  will-change: filter, transform;
}

.card:hover .card__img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: translateY(-20px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.card__link {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.card__link--hover {
  height: 100%;
}

.card__title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ffffff
}

.card__text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff
}
```

```html
<div class="card card__active">
  <a href="#" class="card__link card__link--hover"></a>
  <img class="card__img" src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1064024/10769/i/600/depositphotos_107694484-stock-photo-little-prince-illustration.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="">
  <h3 class="card__title card__title--hidden">Название</h3>
  <div class="card__body card__body--animation">
    <h3 class="card__title">Название</h3>
    <p class="card__text">
      Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вот так края размываются в белый цвет:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.img-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.img-container > img {
  transition: filter 0.4s ease;
}

.img-container > img:hover {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
<img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1064024/10769/i/600/depositphotos_107694484-stock-photo-little-prince-illustration.jpg">
</div>
```

Что нужно написать, чтобы не было краёв белого цвета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё из-за того, что у контейнера был background чёрного цвета:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.img-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, black, #3d3d3db0 49%, black 100%);
}

.img-container > img {
  transition: filter 0.4s ease;
}

.img-container > img:hover {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
<img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1064024/10769/i/600/depositphotos_107694484-stock-photo-little-prince-illustration.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Ага. Всегда размывается с краями. Такая логика размытия по гауссу (не только в CSS). Для того, чтобы этого измежать, слой изображения должен находиться внутри (через `:before`/`:after` или элементом), иметь ширину и высоту равной `calc(100% + [размытие]px*2)` и смещаться влево и вверх на `[размытие]px` (или вправо и вниз со знаком минус).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar ну или background задать нужный для родительского блока

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а размытие краёв - это просто `overflow: hidden` можно задать родительскому блоу

Comment: Но тогда будут края или незаблюренные, или с цветом фона. Т.е не чистый блюр по всей поверхности.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar чётко, только сейчас воткнул о чём говорили